# \begin{flushleft} creates a blank page before title page

Tags: blank-page

When using `flushleft`a blank page is added before my title page. I would like to remove this but am not sure how.
I've read many of the similar "blank page" questions, but didn't find one related to my specific problem. When I remove \begin & \end{flushleft}, I don't get the extra blank page.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,letterpaper,tmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.54cm,lmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm}
\usepackage{lineno}%linenumbers

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.9}
\begin{flushleft}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

\title{Something}
\author{xxx}
\date{}
\maketitle

\linenumbers
\clearpage
\end{flushleft}
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `flushleft` (or the `spacing`) there?  If you want them to apply to your title page, I'm afraid this is not the way to do it...  If not, move the two `\begin`s after the `\maketitle` command.

Comment: Ok well that was a quick fix! Thank you @nickie

Comment: If your aim is to have raggedright typesetting, you should simply use the `\raggedright` declaration after `\maketitle`. Don't use a global `spacing` environment, but rather `\setstretch{1.9}`, at the same location.

Answer (score 2):

Turning comment into answer:

- use `\raggedright`
- use `\setstretch{1.9}` instead of a `spacing` environment (assuming you really want such humongous leading)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,letterpaper,tmargin=2.54cm,bmargin=2.54cm,lmargin=2.54cm,rmargin=2.54cm}
\usepackage{lineno}%linenumbers

\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text

\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

\setstretch{1.9}
\raggedright

\begin{document}

\title{Something}
\author{xxx}
\date{}
\maketitle

\linenumbers

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start the \flushleft after the title:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.9}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}}

\title{Something}
\author{xxx}
\date{}
\maketitle
\flushleft
\linenumbers
\clearpage
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Definetely not, `flushleft` is an environment and should not be used as a macro. If a macro is needed then the proper macros is `\raggedright`